# rendering embedded json in react

Tags: json, api, reactjs, dom-manipulation, react-boilerplate

im trying to render a list of events from ticketmaster api

the request goes fine but rendering is where im stuck

the json comes back as

```
_embedded: {
events: [array]
}
```

i know i can acess this with

```
List.propTypes = {
items: React.PropTypes.array,
}
```

if it was not embedded, so far im let to believe i have to use something like this

```
React.PropTypes.shape({
color: React.PropTypes.string,
fontSize: React.PropTypes.number
}),
```

if this is correct can someone give an example how.

edit: To make things is easier, how do I get react-boilerplate to work with this

```
const requestURL = `https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=&keyword=${username}`;
```

instead of this

```
const requestURL = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?type=all&sort=updated`;
```